# flash lightbox to full screen a div

Tags: javascript, html, flash, internet-explorer

I want to use full screen function in IE for a single `<div>` tag in a webpage. I have  already tried  link for [IE](http://xme.im/display-fullscreen-website-using-javascript#comment-829). But it makes entire screen as full screen I just want to single `<div>` tag to be highlighted `onclicking` the button.

When I heard that flash can achieve that function I got a reference over [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drupalvsgoooglesites/Google-Sites-Embed/flash-embed/flash-lightbox). I just want to use this to work on my IE6. If anyone have known how to do this help me achieve my target.

If anyone has any suggestion??

Comment: IE6 is almost dead, why you want to still support it?

Comment: Just to ensure that if it works in IE6 then it will function in almost every browser

Comment: flash won't work on iPhone mobile browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tv2pP/7/. Make the div position relative and change its width to 100%

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to understand your concept is use

> position:relative

and

> width:100%

to your div